# derivative of a summation - creating a formula for the local maximum of a summation function

Tags: calculus, summation

I want to find a formula for the nth dose derivative of the function
[image]

I have tried to use the first line as my start point but am getting confused. I want a set of coordinates that can depict the local maximum of the nth value. the equations above are surge functions.

Comment: Those summations are just geometric series so you can get a closed form for them. This also applies to the sum with a k.